# ies4linux with selenium and rspec

Tags: ruby, linux, internet-explorer-6, selenium

I use selenium, usually with firefox, to test my rails apps and it's all fine.  I want to run my tests in IE6 as well.  I'm in ubuntu, using the ruby selenium-client gem.  For IE6 i use ies4linux, this is an executable which is at /home/max/.ies4linux/bin/ie6

I'm editing my selenium conf to try to get it to use the above, but can't get it working.  Here's what i have at the moment:

SELENIUM_CONF = {

```
:client_options => {
  :url => "http://awebsite.com",
  :host => "localhost", 
  :port => 4444, 
  :browser => "*iexplore /home/max/.ies4linux/bin/ie6",
  :javascript_framework => :jquery 
}
```

}

Then when i make a browser in my scripts i call

Selenium::Client::Driver.new(SELENIUM_CONF[:client_options])

It's not happy with what i have in the :browser field at the moment - i get this error:

"Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser"

I also tried 
  :browser => "/home/max/.ies4linux/bin/ie6",

But got a "Browser not supported" error as it expects one from list, *iexplore in this case.

Can anyone tell me how i can get this working?

thanks, max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do that. Selenium uses iehta, and some not-so-used parts of ie that could not be bundled in ie4linux, and even if there were, I wouldn't trust on a test that runs IE under linux.

Why not creating a VM using VirtualBox and pointing your tests to an RC server inside the VM?

Comment: thanks santi - i think you're right, it's never going to be trustworthy is it.  The nice thing about running them inside a vm is that i don't get hundreds of windows opening up when i'm trying to code :)  thanks!